# Custom Methods for Treetop Syntax Nodes

Tags: ruby, peg, treetop

I have a [Treetop](https://github.com/cjheath/treetop) PEG grammar that matches some keys. I want to look up the values associated with those keys in a hash I give the parser. How can I make it so that the syntax nodes have access to methods or variables from the parser?

For example, here's a simple grammar that finds a single word and tries to look up its value:

```ruby
# var.treetop
grammar VarResolver
  include VarLookup

  rule variable
    [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*
    {
      def value
        p found:text_value
        find_variable(text_value)
      end
    }
  end
end
```

Here's a test file using it:

```ruby
# test.rb
require 'treetop'

module VarLookup
  def set_variables(variable_hash)
    @vars = variable_hash
  end
  def find_variable(str)
    @vars[str.to_sym]
  end
end

Treetop.load('var.treetop')

@p = VarResolverParser.new
@p.set_variables name:'Phrogz'
p @p.parse('name').value
```

Running this test, I get the output:

```
{:found=>"name"}
(eval):16:in `value': undefined method `find_variable'
     for #<Treetop::Runtime::SyntaxNode:0x00007f88e091b340> (NoMethodError)
```

How can I make `find_variable` accessible inside the `value` method? (In the real parser, these rules are deeply nested, and need to resolve the value without returning the actual name to the top of the parse tree. I cannot just return the `text_value` and look it up outside.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a significant weakness in the design of Treetop.

I (as maintainer) didn't want to slow it down further by
passing yet another argument to every SyntaxNode,
and break any custom SyntaxNode classes folk have
written. These constructors get the "input" object, a Range
that selects part of that input, and optionally an array
of child SyntaxNodes. They should have received the
Parser itself instead of the input as a member.

So instead, for my own use (some years back), I made
a custom proxy for the "input" and attached my Context
to it. You might get away with doing something similar:

https://github.com/cjheath/activefacts-cql/blob/master/lib/activefacts/cql/parser.rb#L203-L249